# Find standard deviation given standard deviation

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, standard-deviation

How would I find the standard deviation of a value, V that is the average of other values, say heights of people, given that I have the standard deviation of the heights? I'm looking to improve my intuition and understanding of standard deviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know that:

- the variance of the sum of independent variables is the sum of the variances
- the standard deviation is the square root of the variance.
- sd$(\lambda X) = \vert \lambda \vert $sd$(X)$, for $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the difference between the average of the variances i.e. (var(x)+var(y))/2 vs. var((x+y)/2)? Which one would I be looking for in the case above?

Comment: I think I'm looking for the second one. And arriving at (var(x)+var(y))/4.

Comment: Would the standard deviation of say z = (x+y)/2 with x and y st. deviations 50 and 70 be sqrt((2500+4900)/4)?

Comment: yes you've got it.